# I am stuck on the first hackerrank challenge in Java

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, sum

This is a simple function that is supposed to return the sum of array elements (integers). The constraints being, there should be no negative integers and the value of each element should be less than 1000.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-array-sum/problem

```
public class Solution {

static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar, int arCount) {
  int res=0;

   if(arCount>=0){ 
     for (int i=0; i<=arCount; i++){
         if (ar[i]<1000){
         res += i;
         }
     }
   }
  return res;   

}
```

**The function I wrote ends here. The rest of the code is as it appears on Hackerrank**

```
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int arCount = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine().trim());

        int[] ar = new int[arCount];

        String[] arItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        for (int arItr = 0; arItr < arCount; arItr++) {
            int arItem = Integer.parseInt(arItems[arItr].trim());
            ar[arItr] = arItem;
        }

        int result = simpleArraySum(ar, arCount);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

**For inputs 6 (array size) and 1,2,3,4,10,11 (array elements), the code returns 21 instead of 31. I don't understand why it is doing this.**

Comment: `res += arr[i]`

Comment: why you tagged java-8 do you want a java-8 solution?

Answer (score 2):

You're summing up indices instead of elements. Also, as mentioned by @Saikrishna Rajaraman iterate till `arCount` exclusive. So, in your `simpleArraySum` method loop change:

```
for (int i=0; i < arCount; i++){
    if (ar[i]<1000){
        res += i;
    }
}
```

To

```
for (int i=0; i < arCount; i++){
    if (ar[i]<1000){
        res += ar[i];
    }
}
```

Additionally, you don't need the condition `if(arCount>=0)` because if it's negative the block inside `for loop` won't be run.

Comment: And also i < arCount or else it might cause array index out of bounds exception

Comment: @SaikrishnaRajaraman Thanks, changed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got so lost after seeing the first bunch of errors I couldn't see straight.

Comment: @Mikoto you're welcome. I'm happy it helped!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problem

- Instead of adding the value of the array, you are adding the index. In your case, it is (0+1+2+3+4+5+6)=21.
- The for loop is starting from **0 to length of array** which instead should be **0 to (length of array - 1)** or **1 to length of array**

Try below solution.

```
  static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar, int arCount) {
  int res=0;

  if(arCount>=0){  //can be ignored
     for (int i=0; i<=arCount-1; i++){
         if (ar[i]<1000){  // can be ignored
         res += ar[i];
         }
      }
   }
  return res;   

  }
```

Also, constraints are for the input values coming in the array. When running the test cases, hackerrank will take care of it. You don't have to explicitly add them to your code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I attempted it so many times I couldn't see wrong from right anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Because you tagged [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) I would suggest this solution :

```
static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar) {// Note: not need to pass the length of the array
    return Arrays.stream(ar)
            .filter(i -> i >= 0 && i < 1000)
            .sum();
}
```

You can test with :

```
System.out.println(simpleArraySum(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11}));//31
```

I also solved the [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/snippets/ef60def4-c832-4dd9-abba-239418d4aa72/laidani-sis-snippet-from-simple-array-sum) Test and I get :

[image: Testcase0]

The other tests are [Testcase1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKtLX.png) and [Testcase2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o39TN.png)

Comment: Yes I've been trying to learn Java-8 although I now see it isn't as easy. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

These days, with the availability of streams in Java, whenever you write a manual loop, you should really think whether you really need to or not.  In this case, you can completely avoid the problem altogether by using a one-liner solution.

```
static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar) {
    return Arrays.stream(ar).sum();
}
```

Less code, less opportunity for a bug, less time spent debugging.